# Image hover - Change effects

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd actually want to change an image when someone hovers the mouse over the image.

Lets say I have an image:

```
<img src="image.png"/>
```

I want to change it with the following effects on hover:

- The image should be clickable, so it should be a link which redirect users to another page
- The image's background should be black-ish, with opacity
- On the image it should appear an other image in the middle

How is it possible to do it?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: you want solution in javascript only or jQuery

Comment: Its only possible to use Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you create a link `<a class="my-image">foo</a>` and use css to get the rollover effect. CSS rollover tutorials are easy to find with a google search and this solution would be the most elegant, semantic and seo friendly you could achieve- without using javascript.

example code from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/basic-link-rollover-as-css-sprite/

```
a {
       display: block;
       background: url(sprite.png) no-repeat;
       height: 30px;
       width: 250px;
}

a:hover {
       background-position: 0 -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make it like this:

```
<a class="superimage" href="http://yourlink.com"></a>
```

and the CSS:

```
.superimage {
    background-image: url(superimage.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    display: block; //or inline-block
    height: (image height)px;
    width: (image width)px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.superimage:hover {
    background-image: url(superimageonhover.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    display: block; //or inline-block
    height: (image height)px;
    width: (image width)px;
}
```

more help? just ask

Comment: (regarding the comment of @PSR) MAN!!! It done with CSS! You don't need jQuery nor JavaScript!

Comment: A single background image applied to hover status too, with a different background-position, will avoid the "no-image" effect while the hover one is loaded.

Comment: exactly, that's called "image-sprite"